# Getting chosen paymentmethod from stripe elements & general stripe flow

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am probably confused by the new Stripe documentation considering I used to work with sources and charges but these appear to be deprecated.

I am using Stripe element with multiple payment methods (card/applepay wallet/ideal) and would like to deal with it server side as much as possible (PHP).

My flow currently is:

- on Checkout page load I post to backend and create a paymentIntent and I return the clientSecret and paymentIntent id.
- The checkout then loads the stripe element with the clientSecret.
- On form submission I post the paymentIntent ID to backend and create a customer
- I attach the customer to the paymentIntent and some other business logic (order creation etc)
- I want to confirm the paymentIntent here, but I do not have the paymentMethod and not sure how to get that from Element and post it along to the backend.

The examples I see in regards to paymentMethods seem to be focused on creating a singular payment method in JS, not necessarily choosing one and sending that along to backend.

Am I going the wrong way about this in terms of flow? Should I instead confirm the payment on the frontend side and deal with the business logic through webhooks? Or actions on the return url? I am using Stripe for both individual payments and subscriptions.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you're accepting a payment and want to save payment details at the same time, I recommend [following this guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment?platform=web). You will create a Customer object first, then include the customer ID when you create the PaymentIntent. When your end user submits their payment details, the form submission action on the frontend will do a few things: confirm the PaymentIntent, create a PaymentMethod object with the payment details shared by the customer, and attach that PaymentMethod to the customer.

This should be the simplest flow to use with Elements and can be used with one-off payments and subscriptions. Stripe recommends [setting up webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/webhooks) for use with Billing anyway so I definitely recommend listening for events so you know what to do next with regards to business logic, fulfillment, etc.